# What is the real part of $\ln\Gamma(-i z)$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I knew
$$\text{Re}(\Gamma(-iz))
=\frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}
\sin(z\ln t)\text{d}t
$$
But
$$
\text{Re}(\ln\Gamma(-iz))=?
$$
Is it has any expressions using integrals?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You shall first define the complex logarithm of $\Gamma(-iz)$.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{Re}[\ln(z)] = \ln |z|$ for all $z$, for any choice of branch of $\ln$.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that the integral you have for $\mathrm{Re}[\Gamma(-iz)]$ does not converge unless $z$ is real. Is that intended to be the case?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're assuming $z$ is real, because otherwise the integral you gave would be divergent. This makes things much easier, because that means $\Gamma(-iz)^* = \Gamma(iz)$. Since we have $\mathrm{Re}[\ln(-iz)] = \frac{1}{2}\ln|\Gamma(-iz)|^2$, we can use the Gamma reflection formula to find
$$
|\Gamma(-iz)|^2 = \Gamma(iz)\Gamma(-iz) = \frac{i}{z}\Gamma(iz)\Gamma(1 - iz) = \frac{i}{z}\frac{\pi}{\sin(i\pi z)} = \frac{\pi}{z\sinh(\pi z)}.
$$
So
$$
\mathrm{Re}[\ln\Gamma(-iz)]  = \frac{1}{2}\ln\left[\frac{\pi}{z\sinh(\pi z)}\right] = \frac{\ln\pi}{2} - \frac{\ln[z\sinh(\pi z)]}{2}.
$$